# Dialog don't dismiss on Samsung Device but dismiss on Google Nexus

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have this question. I have dialog and i want it dismiss. It's work on Google Nexus but it didn't work on Samsung Device. Can anyone answer me, please! This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Insert number please");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        final EditText numberInsert = new EditText(Activity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        numberInsert.setLayoutParams(lp);
        builder.setView(numberInsert);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(numberInsert.getText().toString())<5){
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"again please",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You trying to dismiss the dialog when edittext value 5... So this is prob. occurs and it is crash when you take string value in editext If you want to text than take edittext settype as number

Comment: But why it work on google nexus?

Comment: show the locgat error...?

Comment: I fixed it! Just a stupid problem when i set radius out of rank! By the way, thank you very much @Er.Arjunsaini